# Jquery click to show invisible div (add class) not working in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, jquery-events

I have a "hidden object" game with hot spots you click that then appear to show you found the object.  It works great in all browsers except IE8 and I can't figure out why.

The hot spots are positioned DIVs, set with the CSS:

```
 .hotspot {
  background-color: none;
  position: absolute;
}

#hs1 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

And then 2, etc.  The there is JQuery that swaps this class on click with a "done" class:

```
.done {
  background-color: #ffff00;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

The Jquery is

```
$('#hs1').click(function(){
        $('#textPanel .title').text("CORRECT!");
        $('#textPanel .body').text("blah blah");
        $(this).addClass('done');
        itemsLeft--;
        updateItemsLeft();
    });
```

As I said, this all works in other browsers.  The problem seems to stem from the `background-color:none` -- if I change the initial style to `background-color: #ccc`, it works (but then the hidden spots are not hidden...)

I am stuck any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no value of `none` in `background-color`. Try giving `background-color: transparent;` and check out. I guess that might work!

This is a known bug with IE. When you start, in the `$(document).ready()` give the code to hide after the page has loaded  in IE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hs1').css('background-color', '#fff');
    $('#hs2').css('background-color', '#fff');
    $('#hs3').css('background-color', '#fff');
    $('#hs4').css('background-color', '#fff');
});
```

If this doesn't work, in the CSS, please add `!important`:

```
.done {
  background-color: #ffff00 !important;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It did not work.  Also, my divs are over an image so I can'r set them to white to "hide".

But I did notice that if I clicked on any CONTENT in the div it worked...  if I put like 10 non-breaking spaces.  For now I am putting a 1px GIF to the size of my hot spot in there, and then the click seems to work.  I wish there was another way.

Comment: Oh yeah, `div`s are just containers. Okay, do this. Replace `div` with `span` and check out na?